# gwt celltable: Possible to only make some cells in a column editable?

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I'm using GWT 2.4.  When using a CellTable, I've seen its possible to add a column in which all of the cells are editable ...

```
final TextInputCell nameCell = new TextInputCell();
Column<Contact, String> nameColumn = new Column<Contact, String>(nameCell) {
  @Override
  public String getValue(Contact object) {
    return object.name;
  }
};
table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
```

but what if I don't want every cell in the column to be editable, only specific ones, based on properties in my "Contact" object?  How would I set this up?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it is extend the TextInputCell and override the render method to render something else, if you don't want the value in that particular row editable.

Something like this:

```
public class MyTextInputCell extends TextInputCell {
  @Override
  public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
     YourObject object = getYourObject();
     if ( object.isThisCellEditable() ) {
        super.render(context,value,sb);
     } else {
        sb.appendEscaped(value); // our some other HTML. Whatever you want.
     }
  }
}
```

In the render method you have access to the cell's context. Context.getIndex() returns the absolute index of the object. I can't remember of the top of my wad right now, but if you do not provide a ProvidesKey implementation when creating your CellTable you will get one that will use the object itself as the key. So you can get the object using Context.getKey().

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm still missing something.  In my column, I'm dealing with "Contact" objects.  How do I get a reference to a Contact object in the MyTextInputCell?

Comment: I have defined a ProviderKey, but that only identifies how a particular Contact object is unique (i.e. returns its id).  How do I use that to figure out how to get the object on which the id is based?  Do I have to create a giant map of all my objects and then just reference the map?  Seems like there would be a more elegant solution.  Thanks, -

Comment: Have a look at http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/SimpleKeyProvider.html this ProvidesKey implementation returns the actual object as the key. So when you call Context.getKey() you will actually get you Contact object.

Comment: Wow man,thanks for this!Five years later and you've made me say 'woah' outloud after it worked, THANK YOU! :)